# fontawesome5 instead of fontawesome in komacv?

Tags: fontawesome, komacv

In the most recent version of `fontawesome5` when used with `komacv`, for example with a try of an MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,,DIV=12]{komacv}%
\usepackage[pro]{fontawesome5}%
\faStyle{light}%
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,refcount,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[languages={english,german}]{komacv-multilang}

\begin{document}
\faIcon{envelope}
\end{document}
```

Introduces three errors

```
Latex Error: /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome5/fontawesome5.sty:80 LaTeX3 Error: Command '\faRepeat' already defined!

For immediate help type H .

...

l.80 }

Latex Error: /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome5/fontawesome5.sty:125 LaTeX3 Error: Command '\faWifi' already defined!

For immediate help type H .

...

l.125 }

Latex Error: /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome5/fontawesome5.sty:145 LaTeX3 Error: Command '\faSignal' already defined!

For immediate help type H .

...

l.145 }
```

I think this might stem from `komacv` loading `fontawesome`(which is astonishing that the overlap is then only 3 commands), since commenting out line 48 in `komacv.cls` solves this problem.

What could one do about that? Modify komacv to load one of the packages but never both?

Answer (score 1):

The best fix would be to add an option, e.g. `fa5`  or `fontawesome5` to `komacv`, such that komacv loads `fontawesome5` instead of `fontawesome` if this option is given. But if you just want your document to work without having to wait for a update of `komacv`, you can cheat by pretending that `fontawesome` is already loaded:

```
\expandafter\def\csname ver@fontawesome.sty\endcsname{}% Fake that fontawesome is loaded
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,,DIV=12]{komacv}%
\expandafter\let\csname ver@fontawesome.sty\endcsname\undefined% No longer fake fontawesome in order not to confuse later packages
\usepackage[pro]{fontawesome5}%
\faStyle{light}%
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,refcount,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[languages={english,german}]{komacv-multilang}

\begin{document}
\faIcon{envelope}
\end{document}
```